# Display localStorage in backbone

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm new to `Backbone.js`. I'm using collection constructor to pass data and display in view (`var salecollection = new SaleCollection([{QuotationID: 2,QuotationNumber:'222'},{QuotationID:3,QuotationNumber:'333'}]);`).

And Now I want to display data from `localStorage` instead of taking data from collection constructor.

LocalStorage data is set by the other function, not backbone technique. By (`window.localStorage.setItem`).

Any idea, example would be appreciate. Thanks.

**SaleView.js**

```
define(["jquery" ,
   "underscore" ,
   "backbone" ,
   "models/SaleModel",
   "text!templates/Quotation/saleTemplate.html",
   "collections/SaleCollection"
],function($ , _ , Backbone , saleModel,saleTemplate, SaleCollection){
    var saleView = Backbone.View.extend({
      initialize: function() {
        this.render();
      },
      tagName: '<tr>',
      render: function(){
        var sale = _.template(saleTemplate);
        this.$el.html(sale((this.model.toJSON())));
      }
    });
    return saleView;
});
```

**SaleCollectionView.js**

```
define(["jquery" ,
        "underscore" ,
        "backbone",
        "views/Sale",
        "collections/SaleCollection",
        "models/SaleModel",
],function($, _, Backbone, SaleView, SaleCollection, SaleModel){
    var saleCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
      tagName: 'table',
      render: function(){
        this.collection.each(function(sale){
            var saleView = new SaleView({ model: sale });
            this.$el.append(saleView.el);
        }, this);
      }
    });
    return saleCollectionView;
});
```

**SaleModel.js**

```
define(["underscore" , "backbone"],function(_ , Backbone){
  var saleModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        QuotationID  : "1",
        QuotationNumber : "111"
    }
  });
  return saleModel;
});
```

**SaleCollection.js**

```
define(["underscore",
  "backbone",
  "models/SaleModel"
],function(_, Backbone,saleModel){
  var saleCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : saleModel,
    url: "http://localhost:/Website"
  });
  return saleCollection;
});
```

**CustomerView.js**

```
define(["jquery" ,
  "underscore" ,
  "backbone",
  "text!templates/Customer/customerTemplate.html",
  "text!templates/Quotation/saleTemplate.html",
  "views/Customer/SaleCollectionView",
  "collections/SaleCollection",
  "views/Customer/SaleView",
  "models/SaleModel"
],function($, _, Backbone, WebConfig, CustomerProfile, Sale, SaleCollectionView, SaleCollection, SaleView, SaleModel){
var CustomerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
    },
    el : "#container",
    events : {
        'click #saleTab' : 'sale',
    },
    'sale' : function(){
        var salemodel = new SaleModel();
        var saleview = new SaleView({model : salemodel});

        var salecollection = new SaleCollection([{QuotationID: 2,QuotationNumber:'222'},{QuotationID:3,QuotationNumber:'333'}]);
        var salecollectionview = new SaleCollectionView({ collection: salecollection},{el:'#saleTabDiv'});

        salecollectionview.render();
        $('.containerHis').append(salecollectionview.el);
    }
    render: function(){
        var customerProfile = _.template(CustomerProfile);
        $(this.el).html(customerProfile);
    }
  });
  return CustomerView;
});
```

**saleTemplate.html**

```
<td><%= QuotationID %></td>
<td><%= QuotationNumber %></td>
```

Comment: Whats the actual question? Save the json to localstorage and fetch it back and pop it Into the constructor.

Comment: I just don't know how....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create Backbone models/collections from any data source. Here is an example from localStorage:

```
var Book = Backbone.Collection.extend();

var Library = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Book
});

var model = new Book(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('book')));
var collection = new Library(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('books')));
```

To save in localStorage you could do so like:

```
localStorage.setItem('book', JSON.stringify(Book.toJSON()));
localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(Library.toJSON()));
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I see... so what if the localStorage looks like `{"UID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000006e","RedeemData": [],"AgingData": [],"HistoryData": [{"QuotationID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000001de","QuotationNumber": "891115-0001"},{"QuotationID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000001df","QuotationNumber": "891213-0001"},.....{}]}` , I want to display it from `HistoryData` list.

Comment: I mean, I want to get `QuotationID` and `QuotationNumber` from `HistoryData`.

Comment: Then you will need to parse the JSON and create an object of just the values you would like.

Comment: Could you please show me some example about that? I'm sorry, I really new to it. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I believe that's a separate issue, please accept an answer or rephrase your question, because I believe it's been answered. If you have questions about how to pick certain attributes out of an array of objects, perhaps do some reading on Lodash, `_.map`, and `_.pick` come to mind, something like `_.map(arr, function(val) { return _.pick(val, ['QuotationNumber', 'QuotationID']); });`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I got it now Michael Leaney. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not clear, what is your exact expectation. But I assumed in the following way.

1. You created a collection, where you want store the current/present collection into localStorage variable.
   (or)
   You wanted to store the current/present collection data in localStorage before posting it to the server using sync() function.
2. You've stored the collection using window.localStorage.setItem... as follows

   ```
   var bookModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
   var bookCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

   // Your rest of the functions goes here...
   sync: function(method, collection, options)
   {
     switch(method)
     {
        case 'create': window.localStorage.setItem('myCurrentCollection' , JSON.stringify(collection));
                      break;
        case 'update': window.localStorage.setItem('myCurrentCollection' , JSON.stringify(collection));
                      break;    
      }

   }

   });
   ```
3. Now in a particular view, you want to fetch and show the localStorage value.

   ```
           <% var collectionValue = window.localStorage.getItem('myCurrentCollection');
            _.each(collectionValue.toJSON(), function(data){  %>
            <td> <% = data.Id %> </td>
            <td> <% = data.name %> </td> 
            <%});%>

            //your parse and show code goes here...
   ```

Hope this helps you, if my assumption is correct.

Comment: But Suresh, I just wanna take localStorage to display in my view when page load, after user search... the view will display data from model instead.

Comment: collection is a group of model only. Try adding many models, then store it in localStorage as collection. After that retrieve that where you wanted.